# Deep link to Smart Home Action

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I would like to send users from my app directly to my Action in the Google Home app. Do any of you know if this is possible?

The only thing I can find is a link to my Action in the Google Assistant app, but this does not really give the user any options of enabling the Smart Home Action and create routines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Smart Home Actions, you can implement [OAuth-based App Flip](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/account-linking#oauth-based_app_flip) within your mobile app to simplify the account linking process from the Google Home app. For conversational actions, App Flip is currently [a beta feature](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/app-flip).

[Action links](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/action-links) are also available for conversational Actions.

EDIT:

[Deep links are now available](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/discovery#deep-linking) for Smart Home Actions, and work with Android or iOS apps.